# ios:dismiss and push view controller performing at a time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 view controllers in my current app.

- The **first view controller** has a stream of data.
- In the **second view controller**, an image can be selected.
- In the **third view controller**, the selected image is edited and the edited image will be shared in the stream of the **first view controller**.

---

#### Problem

In the second view controller, I have a `UIImagePickerController` for picking the image and the image goes for editing by pushing the third view controller. I then need to dismiss the view controller after editing the image and also need to push the image to the stream view controller (first view controller). How should I do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try like this [self presentViewController:streamViewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: yes i have used but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to pass an image from the 3rd view controller to the 1st view controller.

You could use NSNotifications to do this.

But you may want to consider a separating the publishing to a stream from the first view controller, and put it in its own (singleton) publishing service.

Comment: can u please send me a sample code i want to do it for image